# Brownian bridge in two variables?

Tags: brownian-motion

Hi

I know about the Brownian bridge, for example $B_t = W_t - tW(1)$.
Is it possible to create it in 2D? ie, to have a 2D Brownian motion, which constitutes a surface, and have it return to 0 when the distance (according to some metric) from the center is equal to some constant?

For example, to have an image which is a Brownian motion realization and have it conditioned as equal to 0 on the unit circle.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "2D Brownian motion, which constitutes a surface"?

Comment: I wrote it to differentiate it from a 2D BM which has BM in x and y axis which gives us a "line".


Answer (score 5):

A natural generalization of the Brownian bridge that should be readily adaptable to your problem is furnished by a [Gaussian free field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_free_field) (see in particular the picture on the wiki page).